# How can I merge consecutive repeated values in list of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I have a list of objects, and I want to merge consecutive repeated values.

In this list of objects we have three values of `(B)` and three values of `(A)`. If the values are repeated and consecutive, I want to merge the existing list at `{list}`.

```
let array = [
    {list:[1,2,3], book:'A'},
    {list:[2,1,4], book:'B'},
    {list:[3,5,8], book:'A'},

    {list:[4,8,5], book:'B'},// *
    {list:[2,8,9], book:'B'},// *
    {list:[6,2,7], book:'B'},// *

    {list:[9,7,4], book:'A'},
    {list:[1,4,7], book:'B'},

    {list:[1,9,3], book:'A'},// *
    {list:[5,2,3], book:'A'},// *
    {list:[7,4,2], book:'A'},// *
]
```

The result will be like this:

```
result = [
    {list:[1,2,3],             book:'A'},
    {list:[2,1,4],             book:'B'},
    {list:[3,5,8],             book:'A'},
    {list:[4,8,5,2,8,9,6,2,7], book:'B'},// *
    {list:[9,7,4],             book:'A'},
    {list:[1,4,7],             book:'B'},
    {list:[1,9,3,5,2,3,7,4,2], book:'A'},// *
]
```

and Thank you in advance.

```js
let array = [
    {list:[1,2,3], book:'A'},
    {list:[2,1,4], book:'B'},
    {list:[3,5,8], book:'A'},

    {list:[4,8,5], book:'B'},// *
    {list:[2,8,9], book:'B'},// *
    {list:[6,2,7], book:'B'},// *

    {list:[9,7,4], book:'A'},
    {list:[1,4,7], book:'B'},

    {list:[1,9,3], book:'A'},// *
    {list:[5,2,3], book:'A'},// *
    {list:[7,4,2], book:'A'},// *
]

    let A = []
    let B = []
    for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
        if( array[x].book ==  'A' && array[x+1].book ==  'A'){
            A = A.concat(array[x].list, array[x+1].list)
        }
        else if( array[x].book ==  'B' && array[x+1].book ==  'B'){
            B = B.concat(array[x].list, array[x+1].list)
        }
    }
    let adds = []
    for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
        if( array[x].book ==  'A' && array[x+1].book ==  'A' ){
            let A = d3.range( A[0], A[A.length-1]-1, -1)
            let obj = {list:A, book:'A'}
            adds.push(obj)
        }
        if( array[x].book ==  'B' && array[x+1].book ==  'B' ){
            let B = d3.range( B[0], B[B.length-1]+1, 1)
            let obj = {price:B, trend:'B'}
            adds.push(obj)

        }
            
        if ( array[x].book == 'A' && array[x+1].book == 'B' && array[x-1].book != 'A'){
            let obj = {list:array[x].list, book: 'A' }
            adds.push(obj)
        }

        if ( array[x].book == 'B' && array[x+1].book == 'A' && array[x-1].book != 'B' ){
            let obj = {list:array[x].list, book: 'B' }
            adds.push(obj)
        }
        
    }
    console.log( adds )
```

Comment: So what did you try? Please [edit] your question to show us your attempt(s)!

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Please revise again to resolve the error in your script.

Comment: Yes I modified that but it still gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've made this more complicated then it has to be, here is my approach (I've probably did that as well):

```js
let array = [
    {list:[1,2,3], book:'A'},
    {list:[2,1,4], book:'B'},
    {list:[3,5,8], book:'A'},

    {list:[4,8,5], book:'B'},// *
    {list:[2,8,9], book:'B'},// *
    {list:[6,2,7], book:'B'},// *

    {list:[9,7,4], book:'A'},
    {list:[1,4,7], book:'B'},

    {list:[1,9,3], book:'A'},// *
    {list:[5,2,3], book:'A'},// *
    {list:[7,4,2], book:'A'},// *
]

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    result.push(array[i]);
  } else if (array[i].book === result[result.length - 1].book) {
    result[result.length - 1].list.push(...array[i].list);
  } else {
    result.push(array[i]);
  }
}


console.log(result);
```

The main part of this approach is this check `array[i].book === result[result.length - 1].book`.
What this does is to check if the `book` property of the element from `array` at the current iteration is the same as the last one from the `result` array.

The rest is just adding the element at the current iteration to `result`. When `result` is empty (first iteration) or when the condition that I've mentioned before isn't meet.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have saved me a lot of work, thanks again sir.

Comment: @BenDavidsson I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Algorithm:

Iterate over `array`, For each object, check if the `book` property matches the previous object. If it does, merge the `list` of the current object with the `list` of the previous object. If there's no previous object which is the first iteration, add the object to the `result` array.

#### for-of implementation

```
const result = [];

  for (const obj of array) {
    const lastObj = result[result.length - 1];
    if (lastObj && lastObj.book === obj.book) {
      lastObj.list.push(...obj.list);
    } else {
      result.push({ list: obj.list.slice(), book: obj.book });
    }
  }
```

#### reduce implementation with demo:

```js
let array = [ {list:[1,2,3], book:'A'}, {list:[2,1,4], book:'B'}, {list:[3,5,8], book:'A'}, {list:[4,8,5], book:'B'}, {list:[2,8,9], book:'B'}, {list:[6,2,7], book:'B'}, {list:[9,7,4], book:'A'}, {list:[1,4,7], book:'B'}, {list:[1,9,3], book:'A'}, {list:[5,2,3],
book:'A'}, {list:[7,4,2], book:'A'}, ];

const result = array.reduce((result, obj) => {
  const lastObj = result[result.length - 1];
  if (lastObj && lastObj.book === obj.book) {
    lastObj.list.push(...obj.list);
  } else {
    result.push({
      list: obj.list.slice(),
      book: obj.book
    });
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```